# Hyperledger Fabric Performance - Multiple Orderers vs Single Orderer Per Channel

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

In Fabric there are two ordering types: Solo and Kafka. When using Kafka, it is possible to have multiple orderers per channel.

In addition to fault tolerance, would having more than one orderer per channel have speed improvements? My understanding is solo would actually be faster because it requires less overhead?

The official docs is pretty light on discussing performance implications regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Kafka, just to avoid the single point of failure you get when using Solo.

In addition to that, the ordering service is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck, as mentioned in the [Hyperledger Fabric paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10228) (Section 5.2). You're more likely going to be limited by computationally intensive signature verification in the validation phase or network bandwidth.